# How to run a bash script with arguments in azure devops pipeline?

Tags: bash, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-tasks

I've a script which works locally fine and while running the script i'm passing 2 arguments in the script and its work perfectly fine, Here's how i'm running the bash script locally:

```
       ./changeDB_connection.sh "fdevtestcuskv04" "test"
```

But, I want to do it through azure devops pipeline and for that I've a pipeline task in which I'm calling a bash script with script arguments but it failed with this error message:  **##[error]Bash exited with code '1'**

Here's the pipeline task:

```
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'Update Mongo Connection String'   
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.UpdateDBstr }}', 'true'))   
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform/templates'
      targetType: 'filePath'
      failOnStderr: true
      filePath: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform/Terraform-Scripts/changeDB_connection.sh"
      ScriptArguments: '-keyVaultName $(kvname) -Stringintials $(strinitial)'
```

let me know what am i doing wrong.

Comment: Without access to the script, all we can tell you is what's already in the error message. Perhaps `ScriptArguments` should be a list, though?

Comment: Quick Duck Duck Going gets me https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?source=recommendations&view=azure-devops which does not mention `ScriptArguments` at all but this could be the normal state of affairs at Microsoft, of course (you are in a maze of twisty documentation, none of which is accurate, and all of which contradict each other).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bowman's answer regarding passing arguments to the script works, but can become troublesome if many arguments should be passed.

I would instead recommend passing arguments as environment variables to the script and then consuming the same variables in the script. This would require some rewriting of your script.

The [documentation for the bash task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops) specifies how to pass environment variables to the script-execution. In short, just add them under `env` in your task definition.

Example:

```bash
steps:
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'filpath'
    filepath: 'my/file/path'
  env:
    MYFIRSTVARIABLE: 'some text'
    MYSECONDVARIABLE: $(aPipelineVariable)
```

Consume the envrionment variables in the bash script by referencing `$MYFIRSTVARIABLE` and `$MYSECONDVARIABLE` respectively. If the variables are secrets, you should keep them in variable groups which the pipeline consumes.

Answer (score 2):

For bash task with multiple arguments you can use YAML multiline syntax e.g.

```
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'filePath'
    filePath: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform/Terraform-Scripts/changeDB_connection.sh"
    arguments: >
        -keyVaultName $(kvname) 
        -Stringintials $(strinitial)
```

Answer (score 0):

The below is a sample, and it works fine on my side.

***xxx.sh***

```
#pass arguments to the script
echo "Argument 1 is $1"
echo "Argument 2 is $2"
echo "Argument 3 is $3"
```

***RunBashScript.yml***

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    filePath: 'xxx.sh'
    arguments: '1 2 3'
```

Successfully on my side:

[image]

Structure on my side:

[image]